# Datafile Handling

Tags: c++

While copying the content of one file to another using the  function, I just want to ignore the first line of the source file and copy the rest to destination.
How to do it?

I copy files like this

I will open ifstream named f1 and ofstream named f2 . Then I will read a line from f1 using f1.getline() and output it to f2.

Comment: How do you copy it? Show us the code

Comment: In order to give any kind of help here you need to provide code because the answer completely depends on what you already have at your disposal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just read the first line and don't do anything with it and write the rest to the output file:

```
std::ifstream f1("intput.txt");
std::ofstream f2("output.txt");

f1.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
f2 << f1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a variable.

In your while or for loop, put an instruction that tell you if you passed the first line

```
     int flag = 0;
     while(condition){
           if(flag == 0){
           flag = 1;
           continue;
           }
     /*the rest of the code*/
     }
```

So, the first line will be skipped.

Comment: Thanks for the help although I didnt understand what you meant.